# How can I create an entry point web app, to manage all other web apps?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, active-directory, microservices

I have several Spring web apps, each with its own database.
Now I have to create a web app, that works as **enter point** for all the other apps..

So if I want to use the web app **B** I have to pass through the **enter point** web app. I have to do the login inside this app. To do that I have to sign in against `Active Directory`.
After that the users can access only to the apps where they have permission, and inside each app they have also some different roles.

what kin of solution can I adopt?

I read about `SSO` but I'm not sure it is correct.. So, do you have any idea?

**EDIT**
What do you think about microservice? Is it good for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are describing microservice architecture and it is a good way to go. You are likely to need OAuth2 for your authentication. I used [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) from Baeldung as a good starting point, although I personally changed the front end from Angular to React but that is down to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. But, why do I need the OAuth2 if I use the microservice architecture?

Comment: OAuth2 allows you to authenticate the user and receive a token, you can use this token across all your services (single sign in)

Comment: To create a micro-service infrastructure, is it correct to use Eureka??

Comment: It not so much correct (as in you don't have to) but it is a good tool to use, and is one that I use. My architecture is: Client app (ReactJs) -> Gatway Server (Spring & Netflix Zuul) -> Discovery Server (Spring & Netflix Eureka)  -> OAuth2 Server & Other resource servers

Comment: So if it is not so much correct what do you suggest to use? And the client are the other web app that I would like to connect togheter??

Comment: What I mean t was it's up to you to use it or not, I personally would, but you question was "is it correct to use Eureka?" Which I can not say yes or no to. It is one of many correct ways to do it. What exactly is your app intending to do? How will your users access it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161536/discussion-between-craigwor-and-teo).

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture must be micro-service and you might use a API Gateway at front of your interfaces, I suggest you to use [Kong](https://getkong.org/) - Open-Source API Management and Microservice Management, that have many features like OAuth2 
and many other.

Then you can have one or more client-sides that calls one entry point to your services.

Comment: I'm looking for some guide to undesrtand how integrate Kong with spring, but I don't find anything... so, how can I integrate it with spring?

Comment: Do your spring app have api interface?

Comment: Kong is an api gateway, if you want to connect directly to MySql you cant use it. But my suggest is going to microservice and use rest interfaces between components

Comment: Mmmm.. I searched online but I read that only postgre is enable as relational db..